# Can't change TableView font-family using both setStyle and CSS editing

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to use "arial" in my tableview cells ,but refused to change , I tried this in my controller class:

```
productListTableView.setStyle("fx-font-family:arial;");
```

and this in my CSS file

```
.root *{
-fx-font-size: 20px arial;
-fx-font-family: "arial";
}

.table-cell * {
-fx-font-size: 20px;
-fx-font-family: "arial";
}
```

I remember it's possible to set it manually from Java using `setStyle()`

Comment: Why the `*` in `.table-cell * { ... }`? Doesn't it work with just `.table-cell { ... }`?

Comment: I tried without the `*`  it won't work too I'm using the `*`, is possible set the font using different method ? like `tableview.setStyle("-fx-font-family: arial")` ?

Comment: I would have thought that would work too.

Comment: Are you sure your css is loaded? Because `-fx-font-family: "arial";` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me

```css
.table-cell {
    -fx-font: 20px arial ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks James & Pavlo ,both solution are working for me on my Windows machine , I always work on Linux environment (Ubuntu) ,after I installed the font manually it work on Linux too .it seems that Ubuntu does not have Arial font by default not like windows .